# Negative power of ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In Silverman's arithmetic of EC he defines the (normalized) valuation on $\overline{K}[C]_P$ as,
$$\text{ord}_P(f)=\sup\{d\in\mathbb{Z}:f\in M_P^d\}.$$

$M_P$ is defined earlier as some ideal. He then says if $\text{ord}_P(f)<0$ then $f$ has a pole at $P$. What does $M_P^{-3}$ mean for example? Does it mean $M_P/M_P^{4}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what definition he's using exactly, but for negative $d$, $f\in M^d_P$ should mean that $fM^{-d}_P\in \bar K[C]_P$. See [this section on fractional ideals in Dedekind domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain#Fractional_ideals_and_the_class_group).